Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.demo.controller.StudentController required a bean of type 'com.example.demo.services.StudentService'
I'm trying to run the application but it shows an error saying "Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.demo.controller.StudentController required a bean of type 'com.example.demo.services.StudentService' that could not be found.
Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.demo.services.StudentService' in your configuration."
I tried everything as possible as I could but was not able to solve the problem. Can anyone help me fix this issue? Thanks
package com.example.demo.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.demo.entities.Student;
import com.example.demo.services.StudentService;

import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/students")
public class StudentController {
    private final StudentService studentService; 
      
    public StudentController(StudentService studentService) 
    { 
        this.studentService = studentService; 
    } 
  
    public Mono<Student> 
    saveStudent(@RequestBody Student student) 
    { 
        return studentService.saveStudent(student); 
    } 
  
    @GetMapping public Flux<Student> getAllStudents() 
    { 
        return studentService.getAllStudents(); 
    } 
  
    @GetMapping("/{id}") 
    public Mono<Student> 
    getStudentById(@PathVariable String id) 
    { 
        return studentService.getStudentById(id); 
    } 
    @PostMapping
    public Mono<Student> 
    createStudent(@RequestBody Student student) 
    { 
        return studentService.saveStudent(student); 
    } 
  
    @DeleteMapping("/{id}") 
    public Mono<Void> deleteStudent(@PathVariable String id) 
    { 
        return studentService.deleteStudent(id); 
    } 
}

StudentController
package com.example.demo.entities;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document
public class Student {
    @Id private String id; 
    private String firstname; 
    private String lastname; 
  
    public Student(String id, String firstname, String lastname) 
    { 
        super(); 
        this.id = id; 
        this.firstname = firstname; 
        this.lastname = lastname; 
    } 
  
    public Student() 
    { 
        super(); 
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub 
    } 
  
    public String getId() { return id; } 
  
    public void setId(String id) { this.id = id; } 
  
    public String getFirstName() { return firstname; } 
  
    public void setFirstName(String firstname) { this.firstname = firstname; } 
  
    public String getLastName() { return lastname; } 
  
    public void setLastName(String lastname) { this.lastname = lastname; } 
}

Student
package com.example.demo.repositories;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.ReactiveMongoRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.example.demo.entities.Student;

@Repository
public interface StudentRepository  extends ReactiveMongoRepository<Student, String>{

}

Student Repository
package com.example.demo.services;

import com.example.demo.entities.Student;

import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

public interface StudentService {
    Mono<Student> saveStudent(Student student); 
    Flux<Student> getAllStudents(); 
    Mono<Student> getStudentById(String id); 
    Mono<Void> deleteStudent(String id); 
}

StudentService
package com.example.demo.services;

import com.example.demo.entities.Student;
import com.example.demo.repositories.StudentRepository;

import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

public class StudentServiceImpl implements StudentService{
    private final StudentRepository studentRepository; 
      
    public StudentServiceImpl( 
        StudentRepository studentRepository) 
    { 
        this.studentRepository = studentRepository; 
    } 
  
    @Override
    public Mono<Student> saveStudent(Student student) 
    { 
        return studentRepository.save(student); 
    } 
  
    @Override public Flux<Student> getAllStudents() 
    { 
        return studentRepository.findAll(); 
    } 
  
    @Override public Mono<Student> getStudentById(String id) 
    { 
        return studentRepository.findById(id); 
    } 
  
    @Override public Mono<Void> deleteStudent(String id) 
    { 
        return studentRepository.deleteById(id); 
    } 
}

StudentServiceImpl

StudentServiceImpl must be managed by spring as well. So place  a @Service annotation on this class
Why is it so? Because Spring already manages the rest controller and creates its instance. When it creates the instance, it must inject the dependencies via constructor (you have one constructor, so spring uses it). But since spring doesnt manage the service it has nothing to inject, hence the error
